# Symplectic structures in rigid geometry

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry

Let $K$ be a non-archimedean valued field (with any further adjectives attached as necessary). I'm looking for references or information about symplectic structures on rigid $K$-spaces.

For example, if $X$ is an affinoid $K$-variety, then there is a tangent sheaf $\mathcal{T}_X$ on $X_{\text{rig}}$, with sections
$$\mathcal{T}_X(U) = \text{Der}_K(U)$$
over affinoid subdomains $U$. It gives rise to a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras $\mathcal{A} = \text{Sym}_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{T}_X$. There is then a "relative analytification'' space $Y = \text{Spec}^{\text{an}} \mathcal{A}$, as described by Conrad in Section 2.2 [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_2006__56_4_1049_0.pdf).

As defined, this $Y$ should be the correct candidate for the cotangent space $T^*X$, and so one might try to make sense of a symplectic structure on $Y$. However, I haven't read anything about tangent spaces or symplectic forms in the rigid setting. Is that because these notions are problematic or because they are obvious? Should tangent spaces to points on $X$ be defined in the same way as if $X$ were a scheme? Thanks for any insight or pointers to the literature.